# Korean text displaying vertically when position is set to absolute (HTML CSS)

Tags: html, css, position

This is a weird problem. I have login screen on a site I am building, on which there is a series of flags that enable you to set the language, when you hover over a flag it displays the name of the language in a CSS only tool tip.

This works fine, except when the language is Korean or Chinese, where the text is arranged vertically like this:

[image: tooltip]

I am not sure that this is a huge issue as I think both of these languages can be read vertically or horizontally. However I would like to know why it is happening, in fact it happens in IE9, IE7, Chrome and Firefox. So I think it might be meant to be like that.

**HOWEVER!** It only seems to happen when the position is set to absolute. Here is my HTML:

```
<span class="tooltip">          
    <a href="/Login/Index?Language_Id=2">
        <img alt="한국의" class="Language_Flag" src="/Content/images/flags/kor.png" />  
    </a>                
    <span class="tip_basic">
        한국의
    </span>
</span>
```

and the CSS:

```
span.tooltip
{
position: relative;
}

span.tooltip .tip_basic
{
display: none;
position: absolute;

background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
border: 3px solid #224E8B;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;

-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

span.tooltip:hover span.tip_basic
{
display: block;    
position: absolute;
left: 1em;
top: 2em;
z-index: 99;
margin-left: 0;
}
```

Now the bit that confuses me is that if I remove the `position: absolute;` bits the text reverts to displaying normally (messes up my tooltips though!) like this:

[image: tooltip2]

Can anyone explain to me why it does this and if there is a way to stop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert on East Asian languages, but as far as I know, they are allowed to wrap between characters.

Something in your code is letting the tool tips "shrink wrap" as small as possible. The best thing to do is find the property this is causing it (it's not included in the code you posted, as far as I can say), or if you can't find it, give your tool tips a specific width.

Alternatively use CSS to stop the wrapping, such as [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space). I think there are other CSS properties that specifically influence wrapping of East Asian languages, but I can't recall them right now. EDIT: Found it: See [word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/word-break)

Comment: **Beware** None of the browsers i tried had any love for `word-break: keep-all;` which i would have thought would do the trick looking at the page you linked to. **However**, `white-space: nowrap;` did the job perfectly in this case. As i said in my question, i think it is the `position: absolute;` style that was causing the issue as when i removed it they displayed properly (but in the wrong place). **Also** setting `min-width: 40px` stopped the vertial text thing happening because there was space for the characters to go with no wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `word-break: keep-all`
[*keep-all* : Word breaks should not be used for Chinese/Japanese/Korean (CJK) text. Non-CJK text behavior is the same as value "normal"].
Tested it on Chrome/firefox/Safari. Seems to be working fine.